# Programmers Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a programmers.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Programmers Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local meetups or tech conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: programmers.stackexchange.com moderator card]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: probably I would drop the "expert" and simplify to just "Q&A site for programmers". The expert part is *assumed* naturally -- and the front of the card elaborates.

Comment: Any news on this idea? Is it still being considered?

Comment: @Anna we're gathering info from the other SE sites too. We should be printing these soon.

Comment: @Jin Awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm certainly interested. Where do I sign up? :)

In retrospect, it would've come in handy at RallyON, and I certainly see a use for it at user groups and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

I like it! It'd be nice to have a card at user group meetings.

One minor nag: can the word "discussions" be removed from the front and be replaced with "questions"?

#### Update

Just came in today:

[image: Business cards]

Very nice. Thanks!

Comment: For that matter, can "discussions" be removed from our tag line and replaced with "questions"? I should bring that up as a separate post, perhaps.

Comment: I will replace it with "questions."

Comment: Sturdy little things, aren't they?

Comment: @AnnaLear Indeed: very nice quality.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be interested too (to make the full house).

Having the cards would spur me on to find occasions where I can use them.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a great idea. Will go great with the (hopefully forthcoming) shirts.

Answer (score 0):

great idea but instead of

> I am community moderator on programmer stackexchange

Should be like

> I am community member on programmer stackexchange

its should be for all contributors

Comment: Top contributors are getting [swag](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/programmers-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!